# Settings required for WCF service on webpage

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have created a WCF Service Application project and created a single .svc file with a single method that takes a string and returns a string. I published the service to our IIS test server (not local machine IIS) and I can see the default page when browsing to http://wcftesting.com/WCFService.svc.

At this point, I am going to create a small html page to test that I can access this service and that it returns data properly. Before doing that I googled around to see if there were any pre-requisite steps that needed to be taken, but couldn't find anything concrete and most of the information was at least a few years old.

Is there anything else that needs to be done to make this work? Everything is pretty standard. No changes have been made to the web.config file, and no additional attributes have been added to the methods. I had seen some mentions of added RESTFUL attributes to the operation contract, but in all honestly I'm very new and wanted to keep things as bare bones as possible.

We are using Visual Studio 2015 and I believe IIS 7.